# Previous Month in Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to show previous month in a calculated field but it just defaults to "Jan" regardless of the date. What am I doing wrong here?

```
=TEXT([Created]-1,"mmm")
```

Comment: Use Date function in combination with year, month and day functions then convert to text.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments above, use formula like:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR([Date Column]),MONTH([Date Column])-1,1),"mmm")
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created])-1,DAY([Created])),"mmm")
```